# Parser function returning a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Two of my colleagues suggested that I **not use a C function to return a `char` pointer**. The way to get a char pointer is to pass it to a function and let the function directly operate on the assigned memory. It sounds to me like an obligation rather than a choice.

Is there a convention like this in C (I see other functions like `strdup` that return a pointer)? What are the **pros and cons of not returning a `char` pointer**? I'm from a Python background. In Python we can have anything returned from a function.

Here's the function:

```
char *parser(const char *buf, char end_token) {
    /* How big is the matched sequence */
    int size = 0;
    while(buf[size]) {
        if (buf[size] == end_token) break;
        size ++;
    }

    /* Output matched sequence */
    char *content = malloc(size + 1);
    if (content == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(content, 0, size + 1);


    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
        char next = buf[i];
        if (next == end_token) break;
        content[i] = next;
    }

    return content;
}
```

The usage:

```
            char *new_path = NULL;
            if (strstr(buf, "/") == NULL) {
                new_path = strdup("/");
            } else {
                buf = strstr(buf, "/");
                new_path = parser(buf, '\"');
                printf("Path: %s\n", new_path);
            }
            free(new_path)
```

What they suggested

```
int parser(const char *buf, char end_token, char *output);
```

I tested with a valgrind tool - it reported no errors and no memory leak. Also, if you find any improvements feel free to add to comments, I would appreciate if you could explain the necessity of such changes.

Comment: `strdup()` might not be such a good example (perhaps there's a reason it's not in standard C?).  If you return a pointer to a resource you've allocated, then you need to very clear about how it should be deallocated.  Manage that and you have no problem, but you get better flexibility if you separate the allocation from the operation.

Comment: This website is about reviewing working code, this question is asking for an opinion rather than asking for a code review. Generally a company that cares about the quality of the code will have a coding standard that would specify something like what this question is asking.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will be prudent next time and hopefully this time the question at least could benefit some of people sharing similar concerns.

Comment: "In Python we can have anything returned from a function." Yes, Python as a completely different mindset when it's about how to get things done. I went the other way around (learned C first, Python later) and kept being amazed by the garbage collection. If your company has a standard set for how you should develop things, rules for consistency, this question is moot. Follow their guide or get a different job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His point (IMHO) boils down to this:

- Almost all functions need to indicate whether their operation was successful or not.
- In python, you use exception handling for error handling. Hence, the error handling is completely different. Most of the time, you don't need to check the sanity of the return value.
- In Go, you can have multiple return values. But it is common convention to use the last return value as an error record, e.g. [ioutil.Tempfile](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile) (`nil` in case of success, error record in case of error)
- In C, you can have only one return argument.

So, what about this approach?

- A function always returns some value with the sole intention to indicate whether it was successful or not (e.g. `0` for success and any other number to distinguish error cases) (just like in Go for most of the functions).
- Output parameters (= return values) are passed as pointers. The result is computed and stored in the output parameter.
- As a result, you expect all functions to return such an error indicator, you can test in an if statement afterwards. Your function calls will always follow the same convention. This is easy to remember and code maintenance will be easier.

Example:

```
int fib_1460 = 0;
int err = compute_fibonacci(0, 1, 1460, &fib_1460);
if (err != 0) {
    printf("Could not compute value: %s\n", interpret_error(err));
    return;
}
```

- `0,1,1460` are input parameters
- `fib_1460` are output parameters/return values
- `err` is the error indicator

I think your colleague argues in this manner. Is it a must? No. Is it a common convention? Most C code (including the Linux kernel) does not follow this convention. I still think the idea itself is good. If every function uses a different way to indicate an error, the programmer will spend more time in the documentation than programming. And C programmers not reading the documentation or handling error cases properly is a huge problem.

PS: You should check the return value of malloc.

Comment: Just one minor extra point. The question starts "Two of my colleagues...." If this is a shared codebase and the existing code uses that convention, that highlights the consistency reason for this particular choice of error handling.